# How to try every bit of a Linux distro without installing it?

Tags: drivers, live-usb, livecd, proprietary-drivers

Using a live CD\USB to try a Linux distribution failed me to test aspects like graphics\wireless drivers. I remember when I tried an Ubuntu live CD it was loaded using a virtual machine so I couldn't test if my graphics drivers will be stable or not.

So is there a way to fully test Linux distributions without having to install them which is a time consuming task and requires formatting the hard-disk with every installation ?

Or at least test the graphics drivers availability ?

Comment: Booting into a live environment should be sufficient to test the wireless and video cards (assuming that the distro ISO has the required drivers)...

Comment: @jasonwryan, it doesn't provide the option of installing proprietary drivers. Or may be I should configure my VM software for that purpose ?

Comment: Are you booting the live environment into a VM? If so why?

Comment: You can also install to a USB stick and then boot off that if you want to install prop drivers and leave HDD alone.

Comment: @StrongBad, I don't remember having an option whether to boot into a VM or not. It just said something like `Try Ubuntu without installing it`. May be I have to use a specific Live-USB tool that actually installs the distro ?

Comment: There's no VM involved with the "Try Ubuntu without installing it", that is simply a "live CD", a bootable, "try me!" version of Ubuntu. Maybe you should reformat your question with specifics as to what is not working that you think should be working.